# Call a method when another one finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in javascript which consists of an ajax call. Let's call it search();

Then I have an event onKeyUp.

In the onKeyUp event, I have an enterPressed() function.

I want to call this function AFTER search() finishes.

I think callbacks won't help here.

Here's my code:

```
function search () {
       ...
}

ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13)
                enterPressed();

}

function enterPressed() {
       ...
}
```

Comment: Callbacks probably are the way to do it.

Comment: also this may be a way forward: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks are the way forward.

Either:

1. Bind your keyup event handler in the callback that fires when the search finishes *or*
2. Set a variable (in scope for both functions) and change its value when the search finishes. Before doing anything in the keyup handler, check the value and, if it hasn't changed, `return` immediately.

(This assumes that the calling of `enterPressed` from the keyup function is significant. If the including of the keyup code is a red herring that just shows that you also want to call it at some other time *as well* then then just use it as a callback directly).

Answer (score 2):

You would use the success/complete callback to call your function on completion. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: enterPressed,
    ...
:);
```

Comment: I need to call onKeyPressed there, not enterpressed. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

After you have finished your first function, you pass the second function as an argument to your first function and execute it at the end.

```
function search (callback) {
    // your code here
    callback();
}

search(function () {
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            enterPressed(); }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var searchDone = false;

function search () {
       ...
   searchDone = true;
}

ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13)
                enterPressed();

}

function enterPressed() {
   if (!searchDone) {
      setTimeout(enterPressed,100); 
      return;
   }

       ...
}
```

You would have obviously to check that searchDone gets true sooner or later... but you have an idea of what you can do now :)